# Secure REST services using OAuth with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

How to secure REST services (OAuth) with Spring Boot?

The closest I can get is:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
http://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: This is a good video from the spring source team

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uBcpsIEz2I

Answer (score 3):

You could add the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` pretty easily to a Boot app. The closest sample would probably be the `spring-boot-sample-secure`, since it explicitly adds a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which is what you'd have to do.  There is no native autoconfiguration support for OAuth in Spring Boot yet (but please feel free to add it). It is on the roadmap, but unlikely to get a lot of attention unless more people ask for it.

Comment: I think it deserves attention, I've spent quite some frustrating time trying to get spring boot and oauth2 to work together (I wanted to use the authentication server) and given up. An example would be great.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted to implement an authorization server. Should be even easier: just add an XML file to your sources with the `<oauth:authorization-server/>` and all dependencies (like from the vanilla [sparklr2 sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/52421af2dcaf61ca8335cfca7e5f83c359c2e7af/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml#L177)).

Comment: I'm not the original poster, but I've done that and I get errors that the authorizationmanager is not specified. It is specified, but created in the java config. Could it be that the xml cannot depend on the java config and must be self-contained?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you do with it. But if all the sources go into the same `ApplicationContext` I see no reason they wouldn't share beans. Can you be more specific about the error (I don't think you mean "authorizationmanager" but I can only guess what you really do mean).

Comment: N.B. also there is a prototype JavaConfig support for OAUth2 in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth-javaconfig).

Comment: And here's a [sample project](https://github.com/scratches/sparklr-boot) - haven't tried it lately, but it used to work.

Comment: Thanks! I got the sample project to work for the authorization_code flow. I did run into `Cannot create a session after the response has been committed` mentioned in https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SECOAUTH-104 when I didn't specify a client secret. Probably due to `http.addFilterAfter(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);`? Adding a client secret and using basic auth solved that. I needed to add `http.csrf().disable();` to prevent naggings about a missing _csrf parameter/cookie in the token request. (Is this correct/safe?)

Comment: Yes it's correct - csrf is a new feature in Spring Security, but I think you can add a custom authorization page that renders the csrf token and then you woudln't need to disable it completely. Details of that are in the main Security samples, and outside the scope of this post.